# Date translation

Tags: language, datetime

I updated ee to 2.9 and now the [Date/Time Language Converter](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/date-time-language-converter) doesn't work anymore

Is there another way to translate ee time?

That plugin wasn't working properly anyway. It couldn't display german umlauts (ä, ö, ü).

Thank you.

Comment: Some idea of exactly what isn't working, any error messages etc, would be very useful to help you with this.

Comment: As far as the umlauts have you tried toggling the "convert_entities" parameter?